# How to customize google maps to receive location specific notifications

Tags: android, api, google-maps, flutter, google-maps-api-3

Can we customize google maps in such  a way to send notifications to users when they approach to a specific location/spot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are talking about **Geo-fencing**. A geo-fence is a virtual perimeter for a real-world geographic area. A geo-fence could be dynamically generated as in a radius around a point location, or a geo-fence can be a predefined set of boundaries (such as school zones or neighborhood boundaries).

There is this [plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_background_geolocation) that i hope will help you.